# I have designed two html pages how to connect them in Java ?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have designed two HTML pages. One is Login page and Landing page. I have Javascript code for client side validation. so how do i import them into eclipse and use Servlet and JSP codes to connect and run the project. For database i used MySql workbench.

Comment: You can search for creating *dynamic web application*  on google.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> how do i import them into eclipse and use Servlet and JSP codes to connect and run the project

You should go through a tutorial first. and post a question if you face problem in following that tutorial.

For startup you can go through: http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners

You'll need a web-server to run your project.

Learn how to setup web-project in Eclipse, assigning server to it, server-configuration and deployment and finally run it.

Answer (score 0):

First create the servlet and then through the "doget" method

```
ad = request.getParameter("ad");//html input name
```

After insert database.. good luck

You can also explore the concept of session.